# Event Driven Processing in Spring With Transaction Persistence (Jdbc) Fault Taulernce

Tags: java, spring, akka, event-driven

I have a spring based project. There are different process that run which take data process it. I need to add an event driven framework that would allow me to call another task/process for processing the data async. There must be persistence and transaction capability. I tried akka, but I`m not able to understand how will I implement transaction. For eg if an actor is expected to do 3 tasks or call three other actors a1 , a2, a3 and if any one of them fails all of the opration (eg. db inserts) should be rolled back. I cannot use kafka as it will require me to install a zookeper server (overhead)

Comment: JDk 1.0.8 Spring 4.3.6

Comment: Have you tried Spring Integration ?

Comment: @PaulNUK I am currently using ejb and activemq directly. I dont want to use a system that would require me to make additional queus. I don`t know much about the integration framework but afaik it provides some sort of pipeline/gateway things and in the underline it needs some sort of queues like amq/ejb

Comment: Spring integration can use existing queues or create in memory ones on the fly. I wouldn't discount it, it's probably the perfect tool for the job.